# Inverting amplifier, k=-2 - Where did I made a mistake? Help needed

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to create inverting amplifier circut with R in range 20kOhm-40kOhm.
I should get magnitued/amplify factor of -2, but I simply cant.
Due to the expression:
k=U_Input/U_output=-R_2/R_1 the input value of voltage should be 4 to get -2 value on output, and simply because of that the resistors should have two values where 2R_1=R_2. But nothing seems to work.
The counterparts for R_1 and R_2 in expression are R3 and R2 on image, also the input is V3
But I think that I am making a mistake somewhere, but do not know where.
Below is SS of my model.

Please can you at least make a hint for me or explain where I am making a mistake?

Thank you for your help in advance!
[image]

Comment: You miswired R2, it sholud be connected between output and inverting input directly, not throught R3.

Comment: Please FULLY explain your problem what do you mean by "there had to be 15v ...". Do you mean you want there to be or shouldn't be or ... . What opamp are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. Do you see the difference?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpxSMU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, but there has to be 15V on both VS- and VS+, It's a part of a problem I am facing :/

Comment: @JakubSzurlej The resistors are wrongly connected, don't you see? The feedback resistor goes from output back to inverting input.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I dont know How I could not have seen this. I'm litteraly blind.
Yes after recconecting them properly everything worked just fine.
Thank you.

Shame on me for such a stupid mistake >.<